# Forgotten trick with Eclipse UI (key combination)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

2 years ago I used some trick with Eclipse UI and now can not remember, how it is done. You place cursor on some element of UI (resource, button, dialog, wizard window, etc.) and press some key combination. A window appears. This window contains short information about this element (java class and something else). What is this key combination? I have looked for it in Preferences -> Keys and could not find anything.

Comment: Are you thinking of the Javadoc display which you get just by hovering the mouse pointer over a method / class / variable?

Comment: @greg-449 No, by hovering a mouse pointer over some dialog, wizard window or something else appears it implementation class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see details of what implements an Eclipse component you use [Eclipse Plug-in Spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy).

The key for this is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try using F2 (Open class, method, or variable information (tooltip text)) or F3 (Go to a type declaration).